# List styling has gone on vacation in mobile user descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The description in [my user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) contains a list, but it's indistinguishable from the rest of the text on the mobile site:

[image: unstyled user description list]

The description lists should have the same styling as their post-based counterparts do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is on dev now, it will be on live in the next production build.